# How to interpret SonarQube effort

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, sonarqube

We use SonarQube go analyze our C# project. SonarQube calucles the effort it takes to fix the issues it finds. I wonder how to interpret this effort.

SonarQube discribes them in their documentation in the following page
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Rule+Remediation+Costs

However, when I fix an issue in my project, I have to test it to see if it still works. Then someone else is scrum testing the finished product. If Sonar estimates 10 minutes. It might take us much longer with all the tests in place.

So my questions are:

- are tests included in the effort by Sonar?
- are the fixes supposed to be so simple that they don't need tests?
- is it assumed that the issue is fixed and verified by unit tests?
- then what about legacy projects without unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The times are estimates to fix the issue and update the tests. Since different shops have different workflows, no processes beyond that are included in the estimate.

With the Governance plugin($) you can adjust estimates on a rule-by-rule basis.